# Master builder in Lego Movie and Simpsons a Brick like me

Tags: character, the-simpsons, the-lego-movie

You know that there was two Lego versions of Millhouse from the Simpsons. one was in the Lego Movie and the other in The Simpsons episode - a Brick like me. But in the Lego Movie Millhouse is called a master builder.

How can Millhouse count as a master builder if he wasn't a master builder in the episode a brick like me as the only two in the Simpsons episode was Bart and Comic book guy

Comment: When is it established that Simpsons are canonical to lego movie?

Answer (score 9):

Simpson is not canonical to Lego movie. Here Simpsons spokesperson’s word on the topic-

> The Simpsons show-runner Al Jean also explained that the episode is
>   not trying to copy The Lego Movie, saying: "None of us saw the movie
>   until very late in the process — long after our story was set."
>   Matt Selman added: "Any similarities are completely unintentional. We
>   didn't even know there was a movie. Nobody at Lego told us about it
>   until after the point of no return. But at the eleventh hour, we did
>   manage to sneak in a little wink to the film. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_Like_Me#Production)

Comment: What was the wink they added to reference the Lego Movie?